# Improving loop that tries different URL variations until match

Tags: javascript, webdav, owncloud

I have build API that connects to ownCloud and gets directory content via WebDAV (using [that library](https://github.com/perry-mitchell/webdav-client)). Because I can't use regular expressions here and glob matching doesn't seem to work while using `deep: true` I have to check all variations of the folder name (because customers sometimes input all letters big or just last name big, but name normally) and that's how I ended with code below. It has a lot of repetition and I this there is a way to make it look better:

```
    // if not found then go level up
    let tryMainDir = false
    let validUrl = () => {
      let url = `${baseUrl}/${caseYearAndMonth}/${lastName} ${firstName} - ${formNumber}/Form`
      return tryMainDir ? url.replace(`/${caseYearAndMonth}`, '') : url
    }

    let isUrlValid = await client.exists(validUrl())
    const updateIsUrlValid = async () => {
      isUrlValid = await client.exists(validUrl())
      console.log(isUrlValid)
    }

   if(!isUrlValid){
      // some names are uppercase and ownCloud is case-sensitive
      do {
        if(!isUrlValid){
          lastName = lastName.toUpperCase()
          await updateIsUrlValid()
        }
        if(!isUrlValid){
          firstName = firstName.toUpperCase()
          await updateIsUrlValid()
        }
        if(!isUrlValid){
          firstName = firstName.toLowerCase()
          lastName = lastName.toLowerCase()
          await updateIsUrlValid()
        }
        if(!isUrlValid){
          firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1)
          lastName = lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.slice(1)
          await updateIsUrlValid()
        }
        if(!isUrlValid){
          firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1)
          lastName = lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.slice(1)
          await updateIsUrlValid()
        }
        if(!isUrlValid && tryMainDir){
          break;
        }
        if(!isUrlValid){
          tryMainDir = true
        }
      } while (!isUrlValid)
    }
```

The loop is supposed to do maximum two rounds. To look inside folder and then in parent directory.

Comment: why are there so many if statements?

Comment: Show code of validUlr() as well for clarity.

Comment: Number of if statements bothers me as well - that's why I put this question on because for sure it can be done in more elegant way. Updated question with `validUrl()` code.

Comment: Would it work to use [getDirectoryContents](https://github.com/perry-mitchell/webdav-client#getdirectorycontents)? You could either use a glob there or just get the whole directory and match with regex against the contents?

Comment: You could probably put all your urls to try in an array up front, including the different parent/child folder paths. Then you could loop over that. I don't think looping in order to try the tryMainDir works very well. It would be better as 2 function calls or with the paths just hardcoded in an array as mentioned, IMO.

Comment: Regarding `getDirectoryContents()` glob I tried this`{ deep: false, glob: "/**/*3604"})` and this one works within directory, but when I change deep to `true` [then I get 500 error](https://github.com/perry-mitchell/webdav-client/issues/199)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you only have to search two directories, maybe you don't need `deep=true`?

Comment: Ye, I even added [issue](https://github.com/perry-mitchell/webdav-client/issues/199) for that. If I don't need `deep: true` then how glob formula should look like? It's the first time I use it.